# Django API TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, json, django, django-views, typeerror

I'm writing an API to save data to a model and am currently dealing with the error that `string indices must be integers, not str`. I've looked online for solutions, including the many questions on this site regarding this error, and have not found a solution so far. I've included a try-except statement in my code for now because the server just says the error is internal and the try-except provides a little more insight into why the code is erroring out.  I've double-checked and am fairly certain that my castings are correct. I've included my code below. Any suggestions are appreciated.

views.py

```
def send_data(request):

    API_ENDPOINT = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/data"
    my_dict = {
        'eventtransactions_id': 0000111,
        'profitcenter_id': 7,
        'customer_gender': 'F',
        'customer_firstname': 'Jan',
        'customer_lastname': 'Smith',
        'actualdatetime': "02-15-2020 18:54:58",
        'custnum': 8880005643,
        'birthdate': "02-15-2000 18:54:58",
        'membertype': 'Student',
        'eventname': 'Location',
        },{
        'eventtransactions_id': 1234567,
        'profitcenter_id': 7,
        'customer_gender': 'M',
        'customer_firstname': 'Joe',
        'customer_lastname': 'Smith',
        'actualdatetime': "02-15-2020 18:54:58",
        'custnum': 8880005643,
        'birthdate': "07-15-1999 18:54:58",
        'membertype': 'Student',
        'eventname': 'Location',
        }
    json_dict = json.dumps(my_dict)
    requests.post(API_ENDPOINT, data=json_dict)

    return HttpResponse("I'm broken.")


@csrf_exempt
def receive_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_data = request.body
        data = json.loads(my_data)
        json_data = json.dumps(data)

        try:
            new_swipe = FitnessCenterSwipe.objects.create(
                profitcenter_id= int(json_data['profitcenter_id']),
                eventtransactions_id= int(json_data['eventtransactions_id']),
                custnum= int(json_data['custnum']),
                customer_lastname= json_data['customer_lastname'],
                customer_firstname= json_data['customer_firstname'],
                actualdatetime= datetime.datetime.strptime(json_data['actualdatetime'], '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S'),
                eventname= json_data['eventname'],
                membertype= json_data['membertype'],
                birthdate= datetime.datetime.strptime(json_data['birthdate'], '%m-%d-%Y'),
                customer_gender= json_data['customer_gender'],
            )
            print("\n")
            print("ENTRY CREATED")
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)

    else:
        print("NOT POST REQUEST")
        return HttpResponse("I'm broken 1.")
```

models.py

```
class FitnessCenterSwipe(models.Model):
    profitcenter_id = models.IntegerField()
    eventtransactions_id = models.IntegerField() #unique?
    custnum = models.IntegerField()
    customer_lastname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    customer_firstname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    actualdatetime = models.DateTimeField()
    eventname = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    membertype = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    birthdate = models.DateTimeField()
    customer_gender = models.CharField(max_length=6)
```

Comment: You are using `json_data`, which is a string, instead of just `data`, the dict, in your code.

Comment: Awesome thank you! That was really helpful in solving the issue

Answer (score 0):

```
@csrf_exempt
def receive_data(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_data = request.body
    data = json.loads(my_data)
    json_data = json.dumps(data) ## This line is the problem.
```

You need to make dump after the try statement. When you dump the value, it becomes string, and dict when you load.

Hope it helps,